# How to ignore certain coding standard errors in PHP CodeSniffer

Tags: standards, code, php, code-quality

We have a PHP 5 web application and we're currently evaluating [PHP CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer) in order to decide whether forcing code standards improves code quality without causing too much of a headache. If it seems good we will add a SVN pre-commit hook to ensure all new files committed on the dev branch are free from coding standard smells.

Is there a way to configure PHP codeSniffer to ignore a particular type of error? or get it to treat a certain error as a warning instead?

Here an example to demonstrate the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <?php
    echo getTabContent('Programming', 1, $numX, $numY);

    if (isset($msg)) {
        echo $msg;
    }
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the output of PHP_CodeSniffer:

```
> phpcs test.php 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 2 ERROR(S) AND 1 WARNING(S) AFFECTING 3 LINE(S)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | WARNING | Line exceeds 85 characters; contains 121 characters
  9 | ERROR   | Missing file doc comment
 11 | ERROR   | Line indented incorrectly; expected 0 spaces, found 4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have a issue with the "*Line indented incorrectly*" error. I guess it happens because I am mixing the PHP indentation with the HTML indentation. But this makes it more readable doesn't it? (*taking into account that I don't have the resouces to move to a MVC framework right now*). So I'd like to ignore it please.

Comment: this is a bit too much of a programming question IMO to be here.. since it's about a "LINT" like utility that would mostly be of interest to hard-core programmers, not necessarily webmasters. But it is nicely asked and formatted, so we can leave it be for now.

Comment: About the line 1 warning: May I suggest using the HTML5 DOCTYPE?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Jeff - I'm happy to move it. I probably should have realised when there was no PHP tag when I created the question :-) .

Comment: @luiscubal - he he, good suggestion; like your thinking ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a solution for removing the "*Line indented incorrectly*" error but first I should say that *dragonmantank* has a excellent point - you shouldn't mix PHP and HTML. It is a recipe for headaches. However, unfortunatly I think mixing PHP and HTML is very common especially in legacy software.

The quickest and dirtyest fix assuming we are using the `phpcs` default coding standards (which are the [PEAR](http://pear.php.net) standards) is to remove the relevant Sniff file. Find the location of the PEAR standards, for me, using [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/), it was here:

```
> cd /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards/PEAR/Sniffs/WhiteSpace
```

Rename the `ScopeIndentSniff.php` file so the sniff that checks code indentation will no longer be executed:

```
> sudo mv ScopeIndentSniff.php ScopeIndentSniff.php.bk
```

**Job done** - now the indentation won't be checked and the "*Line indented incorrectly*" error won't occur (*and your code won't be standard and won't be such high quality!*).

---

The above solution is pretty amateur - the cleaner solution is to create a new coding standard which uses all of the PEAR standards except for your cherry picked customisations. This is very quick to do. Here is how to do it using `getIncludedSniffs()` and `getExcludedSniffs()` and some `phpcs` naming conventions:

```
Go to the directory where the phpcs coding standards are defined:
> cd /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards

Create a new directory for your new standard:
> sudo mkdir PEARish
> cd PEARish

Create your new standard by saving the following in the file:
> sudo emacs PEARishCodingStandard.php
<?php
class PHP_CodeSniffer_Standards_PEARish_PEARishCodingStandard extends PHP_CodeSniffer_Standards_CodingStandard
{
    public function getIncludedSniffs()
    {
      return array('PEAR');
    }

    public function getExcludedSniffs()
    {
      return array('PEAR/Sniffs/WhiteSpace/ScopeIndentSniff.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Test your new customised coding standard by invoking `phpcs` using the `--standard` flag. For example:

```
> phpcs --standard=PEARish Test.php
```

Once it is working you can set your new standard as the default which means you don't need to type the `--standard` flag each time you use `phpcs`:

```
> sudo phpcs --config-set default_standard PEARish
```

See the [phpcs manual](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.coding-standard-tutorial.php) for more information.

Comment: This was really handy - I used this answer to remove errors coming up along the lines of "Class must be in a namespace of at least one level" along with camel case function naming errors. I'm using PSR2 as much as I can, but editing a Magento site, I'm not in a position to go through and rename every function and sort out namespacing.

Answer (score 8):

You're going to run into a lot of issues running PHPCS with your PHP code mixed in with HTML. PHPCS is only really useful when you parse pure PHP scripts. The built-in coding standards are built around pure PHP, not mixed PHP/HTML.

One option would be to build your own custom standard and using that instead. The custom standard would take into account the mixing of code, but it would probably be a pain to write.

The other option is to use a templating system since you said you don't want to move to a framework. [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) and [Twig](http://www.twig-project.org/) can both be used outside of an MVC framework. Move to one of those and then have PHPCS only parse the .PHP files, not the template files.